# What happens to the electrical flux of a charge $q$ when that charge disappears suddenly?

Tags: electromagnetism, gauss-law

Please, check the 2 page of the following pdf file.

https://people.nscl.msu.edu/~witek/Classes/PHY432/Potentials%20and%20Fields/Potentials2.pdf

What happens to the electrical flux of a charge $q$ which is already 
emitted at time $t_2$ when that charge appears at time $t_1$, persists 
for a while, and then disappears at time $t_2$? 
I know that charges can't disappear. It's just a thought experiment.
I'm trying to understand the retarded field.

Comment: Charge is a conserved quantity and cannot just appear and disappear.

Comment: Charges don’t just  ‘disappear’ since charge is strongly conserved. Please clarify.

Comment: @John Rennie I think he wants to say that it is going in and out of gaussian surface

Comment: To Shreyansh : No acceleration. So no EM wave. I mean in case of the standing-still charge. So the flux to infinity lost the starting point abruptly.

Comment: To Jon Custer : I know that charges can't disappear. It's just a thought experiment. I' m trying to understand the retarded field.

Comment: You can’t properly understand the retarded field by thinking about an impossible and unphysical scenario.

Comment: To G. Smith : Check the 2 page of the following pdf file. 
 https://people.nscl.msu.edu/~witek/Classes/PHY432/Potentials%20and%20Fields/Potentials2.pdf